# need to check textarea if nothing typed or defaultValue

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check inside **textarea** if there is nothing typed or default value exist with this code:

```
 if ($("#ipt-content").val() == '' && $("#ipt-content").val() == defaultValue) {
        $("#ipt-content").addClass("ipt-error");
        valid = false;
        emptyFields = true;
    } else {
        $("#ipt-content").removeClass("ipt-error");
    }
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work. Can you please help me guys?

Comment: First try to alert $("#ipt-content").val() and check what you get.

Comment: defaultValue is a line - please type text here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your default value is **line** and condition required **||** ( logical or ) then change your code as below :

```
 var defaultValue="line";
  if ($("#ipt-content").val() == '' || $("#ipt-content").val() == defaultValue) {
        $("#ipt-content").addClass("ipt-error");
        valid = false;
        emptyFields = true;
    } else {
        $("#ipt-content").removeClass("ipt-error");
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

`&&` is the logical AND. You want `||`, the logical OR.

Comment: Yup, actually you were doing : "Is my field is empty AND is equal to the deaultValue" That is ... Always false, a field can't be Empty and filled.